# Why can functions only be called inside other functions?

Tags: c++, c

```
....
void foo()
{}
...
foo(); //why we can not call the function here?

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{}
```

I know you cannot do this, it will cause a compiler error. I guess it may be related to some compiler theory, but can any one can tell me the nature of this, or is it just an arbitrary rule?

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;   

void foo()
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}   

foo();    

int main() {}
```

I get this error message.

> test.cpp:10:6: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘;’ token

Why do I get this error?

Comment: It's not clear what it would mean even if it were valid.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? A function call should not "be in curly brace".

Comment: What do you want to do here? Call a function outside any function? Where's the logic in that?

Comment: "man-made rules"? Not being rude, but C++ is made by... yeah. Maybe you mean implementation-specific rules.

Comment: sorry, my mother language is not english, may be I do not express myself well

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void foo()
{
 cout<<"test"<<endl;
}

foo();


int main()
{
}

Comment: I suggest looking up "function declaration", "function definition" and "function call".

Comment: @user1629199: I've edited your question to more clearly ask what I believe you were trying to ask.  Please let me know if it is what you were trying to say.

Comment: AAh i think you want to say is : a function  call say foo(), why it should be in a { }? But why not any where like foo()..any where, any line without {}?

Comment: yep ,thanks for your editing :D and joey , you really clarify my question

Comment: @user1629199 hmm, 1st of all, its a syntax error.2)What is a program?Its a sequence of steps.And if you place anywhere foo() without any context, does it define a sequence?No.3) Ok, if you called foo() then can you do anything?Anything further?No.Thats why you need to put it inside a proper logical structure like classes, or other functions..Got the point?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
int foo() {
  std::cout << "outside main" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
int Global = foo();

int main() {
  std::cout << "intside main" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now the formal rule: a function call is an expression. Expressions may appear in statements, and statements may appear **only** in functions. But expressions may also appear in other contexts, such as the initialization of global objects - `int Global` above.